# How do I get memtest to see more than one core

Tags: memtest86+

I'm trying to use memtest86+ from the grub boot-loader. After running it I noticed that it said I had 1 core total. I have an Intel i5-4690K with 4 cores so that doesn't match up. How do I get it to see all 4 cores?

Screenshot: [it won't let me add it directly so here's the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3M04.jpg)

Comment: Does it say "1 core" or "1 CPU"? A screenshot or in this case a photo would be easier  to make clear.

Comment: The other question is: does it matter? On a single CPU with multiple cores the memory interface will be shared across all cores and you probably get more deterministic and reliable memory testing by only using one core. Using more than one core for memory testing doesn't really get you much benefit, if any.

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: Found it: force multithreading (SMP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At memtest start when you hear the ***bleep***, you have to be quick and press <kbd>F2</kbd> for SMP mode.

[image: memtest start]

Then you will see all cores running...

[image: memtest running]

But I don't know what difference this should make. It's still a memtest and not a cpu test...